# PHP - Notice Undefined offset

Tags: php, arrays, offset

I have an issue in my php script which I don't understand. I know there are several questions regarding this issue but none fits to my issue.

I actually have one input file delimited by tabulation named `testfile.txt`.

With this txt file, I create a new file named result.txt where I take content of testfile in column 0 and column 7.

When I execute my php script, I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 7

The thing that I don't understand is, my `result.txt` is well created with data contained in my column 0 and 7 from my `testfile.txt`. If I do:

```
echo $dataFromTestFile[7];
```

I have in output contents in column 7.

So I don't really understand why I have this notice and how to remove it.

Here's my php script:

```
<?php
if (false !== ($ih = fopen('/opt/lampp/htdocs/ngs/tmp/testfile.txt', 'r'))) {
    $oh = fopen('/opt/lampp/htdocs/ngs/tmp/result.txt', 'w');

    while (false !== ($dataFromTestFile = fgetcsv($ih,0,"\t"))) {
        // this is where I build my new row
        $outputData = array($dataFromTestFile[0], $dataFromTestFile[7]);
        fputcsv($oh, $outputData);
        //echo $dataFromTestFile[7];
    }

    fclose($ih);
    fclose($oh);
}
?>
```

Sample data of testfile.txt:

```
Input   Errors  AccNo   Genesymbol  Variant Reference   Coding  Descr.  Coding
aaa ddd fdfd    dfdf    fefefd  ref1    fdfdfd  fdfdf   dfdfde
```

Comment: `var_dump($dataFromTestFile)` on the line right before this notice. Most likely you'll see that **one specific row** (or two, or three) don't actually have 7 columns for whatever reason.

Comment: I think, `array($dataFromTestFile[0], $dataFromTestFile[6]);`

Comment: You may check if `array_key_exists(7, $dataFromTestFile)` and if it is false use some default value (i.e. 0) instead of  `$dataFromTestFile[7]` or not write the row to output.

Comment: How can people help you if you don't include some sample data from testfile.txt ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is the line that's causing the error:

```
$outputData = array($dataFromTestFile[0], $dataFromTestFile[7]);
```

You are trying to use array elements at specific index without checking if they actually exists.

Also, you are trying to write an array object to the result file, did you mean to create a comma separated value in that file?

Try this:

```
$source = '/opt/lampp/htdocs/ngs/tmp/testfile.txt';
$result = '/opt/lampp/htdocs/ngs/tmp/result.txt';

if (($handle = fopen($source, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
        if (isset($data[0]) && isset($data[7])) {
            file_put_contents($result, $data[0] .','. $data[7] ."\r\n");
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could write the result as a csv like this also:

```
$sourceFile = '/opt/lampp/htdocs/ngs/tmp/testfile.txt';
$resultFile = '/opt/lampp/htdocs/ngs/tmp/result.txt';
$resultData = array();

// Parse source file
if (($handle = fopen($sourceFile, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
        if (isset($data[0]) && isset($data[7])) {
            $resultData[] = array($data[0], $data[7]);
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

// Write result file
if (sizeof($resultData)) {
    $h = @fopen($resultFile, 'w');
    if (!$h) {
        exit('Failed to open result file for writing.');
    }
    foreach ($resultData as $resultRow) {
        fputcsv($h, $resultRow, ',', '"');
    }
    fclose($h);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your script. Actually, your first script stores only one line of my input file into my result.txt file. Your second script works perfectly, no more `notice Undefined offset: 7`. Thaks again.

Comment: Ah, sorry about the first script. That was a small mistake. `file_put_contents` will overwrite the file with each iteration. Ignore that.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the column 7 exists in your testfile.txt - i guess when starting from zero it may be column number 6 - also you can

```
var_dump($dataFromTestFile)
```

in order to get the content of the variable - array keys and values might be of interest for your issue